# Проверка chekboxa

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно проверить стоит ли птичка на чекбоксе, и если нет то выводить сообщение и не отправлять данные формы, а если стоит то отправлять форму. Как это селать?? вот мой код
http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/QPmEt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// ...
if(!$("#robot1").prop("checked")) { 
    $('.btn').before('<p class="inputs_error">Подтвердите, что Вы не робот.</p>');
    return false;
}
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать selector `:checked` :

```
if(!$("#robot1").is(":checked")) { 
            $('.btn').before('<p class="inputs_error">Подтвердите, что Вы не робот.</p>');
            return false;
        }
```

вот так я бы делал, вместо добавления текста каждый раз, кроме того обработчик надо вешать на submit формы а не на клик по кнопке submit.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QPmEt/5/